# PySpark equivalent of pandas read_sql_query

Tags: python, sql, pandas, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to switch from pandas to pyspark and usually when I did my analysis I used `pd.read_sql_query` to read the data needed for the analysis from a redshift database.

Example:

```
query = '''
SELECT id, SUM(value)
FROM table
GROUP BY id
'''

df = pd.read_sql_query(query, engine)
```

Is there any equivalent function in PySpark? Something that receives a query and a SQLAlchemy engine and returns the result of the query? If not, what is the best way to get a result of a SQL query in pyspark?

I tried to find something in `pyspark.SQLContext` but didn't find anything useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use **`spark.sql()`** API to run your query.

**`Example:`**

```
query='select 1'
spark.sql(query).show()
#+---+
#|  1|
#+---+
#|  1|
#+---+
```

To run the query on any **`RDBMS`** db's then use [`spark.read.format("jdbc")`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-jdbc.html) to establish connection and execute your query.

```
spark.read.format("jdbc").option(...).load()
```

Comment: Great! Thanks for the help